# Regex that includes slash and asterix as constant

Tags: regex, go

I am using Golang and I am trying to determine which regex will work to match any string that starts with:

```
/*
```

It has been dificult to get it, I tried many ways (I didn't save them all to writte them here), but some of them are:

```
{/*}.*?
//*.*?
//\\*[A-Za-z0-9_-]*$
```

Comment: Like in any other language: ^/\*

Comment: If that's your only requirement, don't use a regex. Use `strings.HasPrefix` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to match the **whole** source text, the regex must start with `^`
and end with `$` (anchors).

To match `/` use just `/`. In some other host languages (e.g. Javascript or Perl)
slashes are used as regex delimiters, so to use the slash as the **content**
of regex, you would have to escape it with a backslash, but in *go* this is not needed.

To match `*` use `\*`. You can not use just `*` (as *Volker* proposed), because it is a **quantifier**, meaning *0 or more*.

As you want to match **the whole string** (not just `/*`), the next part
should be `.*` (any number of any chars).

If you want to catch the "rest" of string in a capturing group, surround
this part with parentheses.

And the last step of complication: Usually after `/*` there are some spaces
and only after them the fragment you actually want to catch. In such case:

- start from `\s*` (optional sequence of white chars),
- then put `(.*)`.

So the final solution is: `^/\*\s*(.*)$`

For a working example see https://regex101.com/r/80ORab/1

### Edit

If you write your regex as a string, in double quotes, the backslash
must be written twice.

Comment: Sorry. I typed the backslash, but it seems it doesnt make it to the output of the comment. Of course I did not propose /*.

Answer (score 3):

You need to escape the `*` with a backslash: `^/\*`. However, if you use normal quotation marks, you need to escape that backslash itself as well:

`"^/\\*"`

Alternatively, you can use a raw string literal, which does not need the escaping of the backslash:

`` `^/\*` ``

Playground link: https://play.golang.org/p/v5y9l8dTXRs